# Integrating by parts using natural log

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the problem:

$$ \int\frac{-3}{800+2t}\,dt$$

If I factor a $2$ out of the denominator:

$$ \frac{-3}{2}\int\frac{1}{400+t}\,dt$$

Integration by parts then gets the result:

$$\frac{-3}{2}\ln(400+t)+C$$

However, if I do not factor out the 2 initially and integrate by parts I get:

$$\frac{-3}{2}\ln(800+2t)+C$$

Which one is correct and how do I reconcile this discrepancy?

Wolfram Alpha gave some reasoning for "restricted t values"

Comment: $\ln(800 + 2t) = \ln(2(400 + t)) = \ln(400 + t) + \ln2 = \ln(400 + t) + C$

Comment: I don't think that's integration by parts, but rather a substitution $u=400+t$.

Comment: To elaborate on what @FlameTrap said, both your answers are correct. Remember that indefinite integrals are defined only up to adding a constant. The reason we always add $+ C$ is because if we come up with one answer for the indefinite integral (such as $\ln(400 + t)$), we can get another answer by adding any constant (such as $\ln 2$ - we see that $\ln(400 + 2) + \ln 2 = \ln (800 + 2t)$).

Comment: "Wolfram Alpha gave some reasoning for 'restricted t values'".  What is $\ln(400+t)$ when $t \leq -400$ ?  That is the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Both results are correct.

As, $$\dfrac{-3}{2}\ln(800+2t)+C_{1}= \dfrac{-3}{2}\ln(2(400+t))+C_{1}= \dfrac{-3}{2}\ln(400+t)+\dfrac{-3}{2}\ln(2)+C_{1}= \dfrac{-3}{2}\ln(400+t)+C$$

Comment: Yeah both constants are different. But both results are correct , an integral can have more than 1 correct result.

Comment: nice answer!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$